# Push event not firing on send notification from server

Tags: java, push-notification, service-worker, web-push, vapid

I want to push notification from my server.for that i am using web push API for java , i am able to send the notification to endpoint url but on receiver side my service worker not executing push event,As I am using VAPID so no need to use gcm Id as per my understanding,here you are my service worker file.

```
'use strict';

const applicationServerPublicKey = 'BEl62iUYgUivxIkv69yViEuiBIa-Ib9-
SkvMeAtA3LFgDzkrxZJjSgSnfckjBJuBkr3qBUYIHBQFLXYp5Nksh8U';

function urlB64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
  const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
  const base64 = (base64String + padding)
    .replace(/\-/g, '+')
.replace(/_/g, '/');

const rawData = window.atob(base64);
const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);

for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
  outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
}
return outputArray;
}
self.addEventListener('install', function(event){
 event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting());
 console.log("activate");
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event){
event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
 console.log("install");
});

self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log('Received push');
  let notificationTitle = 'Hello';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Thanks for sending this push msg.',
    icon: '/JMS/resources/images/icon.png',
    badge: '/JMS/resources/images/badge.png',
    tag: 'simple-push-demo-notification',
    data: {
      url: 'https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-
      started/push-notifications/',
    },
  };

  if (event.data) {
    const dataText = event.data.text();
    notificationTitle = 'Received Payload';
    notificationOptions.body = `Push data: '${dataText}'`;
  }

    event.waitUntil(
    Promise.all([
      self.registration.showNotification(
        notificationTitle, notificationOptions),
    ])
  );
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    event.notification.close();
    event.waitUntil(
            clients.openWindow('https://www.auctiontiger.net')
          );
  let clickResponsePromise = Promise.resolve();
  if (event.notification.data && event.notification.data.url) {
    clickResponsePromise = clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url);
  }

  event.waitUntil(
    Promise.all([
      clickResponsePromise
    ])
  );
});
```

here you are my main.js file from where i am able to call to my local server.

```
'use strict';

const applicationServerPublicKey = 'BEl62iUYgUivxIkv69yViEuiBIa-Ib9-
SkvMeAtA3LFgDzkrxZJjSgSnfckjBJuBkr3qBUYIHBQFLXYp5Nksh8U';
const pushButton = document.querySelector('.js-push-btn');

let isSubscribed = false;
let swRegistration = null;

function urlB64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
const base64 = (base64String + padding)
.replace(/\-/g, '+')
.replace(/_/g, '/');

const rawData = window.atob(base64);
const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);

for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
}
return outputArray;
}

function updateBtn() {
if (Notification.permission === 'denied') {
pushButton.textContent = 'Push Messaging Blocked.';
pushButton.disabled = true;
updateSubscriptionOnServer(null);
return;
}

    if (isSubscribed) {
     pushButton.textContent = 'Disable Push Messaging';
     } else {
     pushButton.textContent = 'Enable Push Messaging';
     }

     pushButton.disabled = false;
    }

  function updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription) {
  // TODO: Send subscription to application server

const subscriptionJson = document.querySelector('.js-subscription-json');
const subscriptionDetails =
document.querySelector('.js-subscription-details');

if (subscription) {
subscriptionJson.textContent = JSON.stringify(subscription);
subscriptionDetails.classList.remove('is-invisible');
 } else {
 subscriptionDetails.classList.add('is-invisible');
 }
 }

function subscribeUser() {
const applicationServerKey = urlB64ToUint8Array(applicationServerPublicKey);
swRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({
userVisibleOnly: true,
applicationServerKey:applicationServerKey 

  })
 .then(function(subscription) {
  updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription);
  isSubscribed = true;
  updateBtn();
  initialiseUI();
  return sendSubscriptionToServer(subscription);
  })
   .catch(function(err) {
   console.log('Failed to subscribe the user: ', err);

   });
   }
function sendSubscriptionToServer(subscription) {
var key = subscription.getKey ? subscription.getKey('p256dh') : '';
var auth = subscription.getKey ? subscription.getKey('auth') : '';

return fetch('/JMS/profile/subscription', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        endpoint: subscription.endpoint,
        // Take byte[] and turn it into a base64 encoded string suitable for
        // POSTing to a server over HTTP
        key:key ? btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(key))) 
        : '',
        auth:auth ? btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new 
        Uint8Array(auth))) : ''
    })
    });

     }

   function unsubscribeUser() {
   swRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
  .then(function(subscription) {
   if (subscription) {
    return subscription.unsubscribe();
   }
   })
  .catch(function(error) {
  console.log('Error unsubscribing', error);
   })
  .then(function() {
  updateSubscriptionOnServer(null);

  console.log('User is unsubscribed.');
  isSubscribed = false;

  updateBtn();
  });
  }

   function initialiseUI() {
   pushButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
   pushButton.disabled = true;
   if (isSubscribed) {
    unsubscribeUser();
   } else {
  subscribeUser();
    }
    });

   // Set the initial subscription value
    swRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
    .then(function(subscription) {
    isSubscribed = !(subscription === null);

    updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription);

      if (isSubscribed) {

        console.log('User IS subscribed.');
      } else {
     console.log('User is NOT subscribed.');
      }

       updateBtn();
      });
      }

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'PushManager' in window) {
    console.log('Service Worker and Push is supported');

    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
    .then(function(swReg) {
    console.log('Service Worker is registered', swReg.scope);
    swReg.update();
    swRegistration = swReg;
    initialiseUI();
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
    console.error('Service Worker Error', error);
    });
    } else {
    console.warn('Push messaging is not supported');
    pushButton.textContent = 'Push Not Supported';
    }
```

here is the URL for webpush API that i have used for my application,
[https://github.com/web-push-libs/webpush-java][1]
finally my server side code,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "profile/subscription", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
headers = "Content-Type=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public String post(@RequestBody String body,byte[] 
    payload,HttpServletResponse response)
            throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, JoseException, 
    ExecutionException, InterruptedException, ParseException, JSONException 
    {
    String data="";
    org.json.JSONObject ob = new org.json.JSONObject(body);
    final int TTL = 255;
    payload= "hello".getBytes(); 
    com.demo.controller.PushService pushService = new  
    com.demo.controller.PushService();
    nl.martijndwars.webpush.Notification notification =new 
    nl.martijndwars.webpush.Notification(ob.getString("endpoint")
   ,new Subscription().getUserPublicKey((ob.getString("key"))),
    Base64.decode(ob.getString("auth")), 
    payload,TTL);
    pushService.send(notification);
    org.json.JSONObject ob2 = new org.json.JSONObject(body);
    ob2.put("data", notification.getPayload());
    JSONArray arr= new JSONArray();
    arr.add(ob2);
    data=arr.toJSONString();
    response.setHeader("Service-Worker-Allowed", "/"); 
    return data;
   }
```

actually I am fetching this from client browser and on server-side sending notification on the endpoint, and i am able to send the notification but my 
service worker is not able to fire push event so i am not getting notification on my browser.

```
  {
  auth:"hcQQq+1FeDuSu7V0zd5DXA==" 
  endpoint:"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/
  cXgp0l3svNo:APA91bG8dDfZhrc0iaSyzvuV1BvnxXz9T-
  SmLCKOymKrEdwvrh0_SjzjnU3ORRKvW5QD-
  Zp196T5nAGPayR7EKu_Bkb0pQrSex7Q3DZSu54Lo83AEiUE6p-2Xn-nrquCymKVFt6Z4nY8"
  key:"BJv2qC3WSCsRszMi57vOBpFjnIpdJ/
  uXQQFj4d0XZD9lRuZKuBgJNVFra0SFEvRlQQ88eG8RWWs7sSvO9Pbdkwk="
  }
```

Please help me to get out of this, any help would be greatly appreciated.Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say "I am able to send the notification" do you mean that you get a successful response code (i.e. 2xx) from the push service? If not, you must check the HTTP response code

Comment: yes I am getting success response code 200.

Comment: As its all on VAPID ,we don't need to create any project in fcm and gcm , is it possible to see the messages that i have sent ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be due to some firewall blocking you from receiving the push notification. This was the case with me.